# Ruflin/Elastica bulk insert without update

Tags: elasticsearch, bulk, elastica

I have a code which needs to insert a huge among of data BUT ONLY if doc _id does not exists in the index. 
I found something like this:

```
foreach($item as $i)
{
        $elasticBulk[] = new \Elastica\Document( $item->id, ['ico' => $item->id] );
}

$elasticType = $searchIndex->getType('doc');
$elasticType->addDocuments( $elasticBulk );
```

BUT this code rewrites all stored items. I need to insert document from bulk only if does not exists in database. Can somebody tell me how to do it in Ruflin/Elastica library?

Answer (score 1):

So I think I have it. If somebody needs to know here is the solution:

```
foreach( $items as $item )
{
    $doc = new \Elastica\Document( $item->id, ['ico' => $item->id] );
    $doc->setType($searchIndex->getType( 'doc' ));
    $elasticBulk[] = $doc;
}

$bulk = new \Elastica\Bulk($elastic);
$bulk->addDocuments($elasticBulk, \Elastica\Bulk\Action::OP_TYPE_CREATE);

try
{
    $bulk->send();
}
catch( \Elastica\Exception\Bulk\ResponseException $e )
{
}
```